# StackEnsemble in Deep Learning

Tags: python, deep-learning, stack, ensemble-learning

I have been trying StackEnsemble with the library DeepStack. First model is VGG16, second one is VGG19 and last one is CNN with 6 fully connected layers.

```
# Load Keras Models

model1 = tf.keras.models.load_model('VGG16.h5')

model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model('vgg19.h5')

model3 = tf.keras.models.load_model('basic_cnn.h5')

from deepstack.base import KerasMember

member1 = KerasMember(name="model1", keras_model=model1, train_batches=train_generator, val_batches=validation_generator)
member2 = KerasMember(name="model2", keras_model=model2, train_batches=train_generator, val_batches=validation_generator)
member3 = KerasMember(name="model3", keras_model=model3, train_batches=train_generator, val_batches=validation_generator)


from deepstack.ensemble import StackEnsemble
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

#Ensure you have the scikit-learn version >= 0.22 installed
print("sklearn version must be >= 0.22. You have:", sklearn.__version__)

stack = StackEnsemble()

# 2nd Level Meta-Learner
estimators = [
    ('rf', RandomForestClassifier(verbose=0, n_estimators=200, max_depth=15, n_jobs=20, min_samples_split=30)),
    ('etr', ExtraTreesClassifier(verbose=0, n_estimators=200, max_depth=10, n_jobs=20, min_samples_split=20))
]
# 3rd Level Meta-Learner
clf = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=estimators, final_estimator=LogisticRegression()
)

stack.model = clf
stack.add_members([member1, member2, member3])
stack.fit()
stack.describe(metric=sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score)
```

The code is running smoothly till here but the below is givin error.

```
predictions = stack.predict_generator(test_generator)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-5442787a7d9e> in <module>
      1 #Making prediction on test images using predict_trainer
      2 
----> 3 predictions = stack.predict_generator(test_generator)

AttributeError: 'StackEnsemble' object has no attribute 'predict_generator'
```

Comment: Why mixing stacking functionality from  DeepStack and scikit-learn? Doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/jcborges/DeepStack/blob/master/deepstack/ensemble.py) -

If I understand correctly, it would seem as though the error simply means that the stack object that you have defined has no callable function 'predict_generator'. Rather, use `predictions = stack.predict(test_generator)` which will then call the predict function associated with your CNN and return the predicted probabilities as an np.array.